# Read from html 5 local storage with selenium

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium

I am using selenium web driver in c#.
when i write to local storage with JavaScript method it works fine 
( i can see the values in the html page with inspect ), but if i try to read from local storage  what i just wrote it returns Null.
Thanks for any help .

Writing (works):

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;      
js.ExecuteScript("localStorage.setItem('key','value');");
```

Reading (returns Null ):

```
Object Value= js.ExecuteScript("localStorage.getItem('key')");
```

Comment: The Selenium API has a `local_storage` endpoint: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/local_storage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should return the value, secondly you should cast the return value to a known type.

```
value = (String) js.executeScript("return localStorage.getItem('key')");
```

Comment: From version 2.42 of selenium you can use `webDriver.getLocalStorage()` if the driver supports it.

Comment: Currently `getLocalStorage()` exists just for the Chrome Driver (and Android Driver, from what I can see)

Comment: browser.WebStorage.LocalStorage.GetItem("item")

Answer (score 3):

Update to the question, in 2018 with c# you would do:

```
browser.WebStorage.LocalStorage.GetItem("item")
```